# How should I add fields without adding them to a GROUP BY?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a SQL statement that works as-is. I get an area name and the minimum value within that area. next, I need to add in a key so I can actually do something with the results. The key is necessary since names and values are unlikely to be unique.

```
select g.name, min(g.rndval) from
(
    select p.rndval, a.name, p.id
    from points p, areas a
    where ST_WITHIN(p.geom, a.geom)
) AS g
group by g.name
```

When I add the Id field to the group by, the query returns multiple rows for each area, as expected since it's grouping by the name and id combination, and the results are no longer what I need. How should I add in the id field (p.id in the inner select)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
WITH cte AS
(  select p.rndval, a.name, p.id
   from points p, areas a
   where ST_WITHIN(p.geom, a.geom)
), cte_aggregated AS
(
   SELECT name, min(rndval) AS min_value
   FROM cte
   GROUP BY name
)
SELECT DISTINCT c.rndval, c.name, c.id
FROM cte c
JOIN cte_aggregated ca
  ON c.rndval = ca.min_value
 AND c.name = ca.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this quite elegantly with a window function:

```
select name, rndval as min, id
from (
  select a.name, p.rndval, p.id, rank() over (partition by a.name order by p.rndval) as rnk
  from points p
  join areas a on ST_Within(p.geom, a.geom)) as g
where rnk = 1;
```